# How to ensure a simple interpolation algorithm doesn't go the long way when used with degrees?

Tags: java, algorithm, rotation

My program reads in a pitch and yaw, and then attempts to smoothly interpolate to that pitch and yaw from the current rotation.

However, I'm encountering an issue due to how the interpolation works.

Assume a simple move-towards interpolation that moves from the current value to the new one by 1 every tick.

If given a current pitch of 20, and a new pitch of 330, it will rotate in the positive direction 310 degrees. However, it would be faster to rotate in the negative direction 50 degrees (since 0 = 360)

What's the best way to make this work with an interpolation algorithm (preferably without rewriting the interpolation)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If the absolute delta is more than 180 degrees, you can add/subtract (depending on the sign of the delta) 360 degrees to the delta to reduce the absolute delta value and "go the short way".